# Explicit expression for $\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-\alpha\cos(\theta)(1+\gamma\cos(\theta))}d\theta$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

Working on some probability distributions and I'm stuck with getting an analytical expression for

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-\alpha\cos(\theta)(1+\gamma\cos(\theta))}d\theta$$

$\alpha$ is positive, $\gamma$ can be either way.
Any tips are welcome!

Comment: Is there any reason you have to suspect that it has a nice analytical form? I suspect you can make something work using Bessel functions but that's about as good as you'll get.

Comment: Wishful thinking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know if a closed form solution exists but, *may be*, a series solution.

Writing
$$e^{\alpha  \cos (\theta ) (1+\gamma  \cos (\theta ))}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\alpha ^n \gamma ^n}{n!}\, e^{\alpha \, \cos (\theta )} \cos ^{2 n}(\theta )$$
$$I_n=\int_0^{2\pi}   e^{\alpha \, \cos (\theta )} \cos ^{2 n}(\theta )\,d\theta$$
$$I_n=2 \sqrt{\pi }\,\,\frac{ \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{n!}\,\,\, _1F_2\left(n+\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2},n+1;\frac{\alpha
   ^2}{4}\right)$$
The term
$$T_n=\frac{4^n}{\binom{2 n}{n}}\,\alpha^n \, _1F_2\left(n+\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2},n+1;\frac{\alpha
   ^2}{4}\right)$$ is a linear combination of $I_n(\alpha )$ and $I_{n+1}(\alpha )$ weighted by polynomials in $\alpha$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & T_n \\
 0 & I_0(\alpha ) \\
 1 & I_1(\alpha )+\alpha  I_2(\alpha ) \\
 2 &  \left(\alpha ^2+3\right) I_2(\alpha ) \\
 3 & 5 \left(\alpha ^2+3\right) I_3(\alpha
   )+\alpha  \left(\alpha ^2+5\right) I_4(\alpha ) \\
 4 & \left(\alpha
   ^4+42 \alpha ^2+105\right) I_4(\alpha )+4 \alpha ^3 I_5(\alpha ) \\
 5 & \left(13 \alpha ^4+378 \alpha ^2+945\right)
   I_5(\alpha )+\alpha  \left(\alpha ^4+42 \alpha ^2+189\right)
   I_6(\alpha ) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$